# Multi View slide on scrollview

Tags: ios, ipad, uiscrollview, touch, swipe

I'm making an App for iPad.

But I faced some troubles because of Touch Event of ScrollView.
I have tried with iphone sample code [[link]](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/WindowsViews/Conceptual/UIScrollView_pg/ScrollViewPagingMode/ScrollViewPagingMode.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40008179-CH3-SW1), but I can't get what I want through this sample.
The reason is that my app is only for iPad.

I add my sketchy pic.

-- image link : https://lh5.googleusercontent.com/-x7TsXmxv1XU/TsYSkEh-3VI/AAAAAAAAAB8/ECn3MjiFF6Y/s512/IMG_20111118_170519.jpg

I add UIScrollView on ViewController, and add UIViews on this UIScrollView.

UIViews on this UIScrollView must be hidden outside of UIScrollView. But can't be hidden. @.@
And I can't use touch event on UIScrollView - left and right.
What I want is how to use touch event on scroll view.

I searched about this in Stack Overflow and google.
I could find many articles, but unfortunately I can't understand clearly.

Please explain me more easily. I'm a beginner programmer.

Comment: Your question is very unclear. Basically, you're only asking how to do 'something' with 'touch events' in a scrollview. Both of these terms are very broad. You'll have to be more specific, or we can't answer your question.

Comment: @Aberrant Thanks your advice. Truly says that I don't know how to way uploading my sample source code. If I don't success, will ask again with specific code. Re-Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

make your scrollview to clip subviews by it's bounds:

```
scrollView.clipToBounds = YES;
```

this will resolve your "un-hidden views" issue

Comment: Ah! Thanks!!! But I'm sorry that my question is incorrect. What I want is how to use touch event on scroll view. So now edited my writing.

Comment: why do you need raw touch-event? UIScrollViewDelegate implementation is a place, where you need to handle all scrolling events